# How to use unwrap function and iota( "i" in complex numbers ) in C?

Tags: c++, c, gsl

I am developing code in C language to get a population spectra of a system. In this spectra, I need to unwrap function to perform further steps of my systems.

1. Can anyone tell me, how to use unwrap function in my code?
2. How can I use iota ("i" in complex number) in my code?
3. finally How I can use gsl fft function to perform Fourier transform of a function?

I have declared all parameters properly in the code below mentioned is an only segment of code where I need your help.

1. In function of ph1, I need to unwrap phi
2. In function of D and N, I have used iota as "i" Plz help me out how could I use it?
3. Finally, I want to perform fft of S using gsl. How can it be done?

Here is the code:

```
double dt = 0.01;
double N1 = 11;
double Fs = 1 / dt;
a = dt * (N1 - 1);
double dx = 1 / a;
double N;
for (m = 1; m <= N1; m++) {
    double t1 = (m - 1) * dt;
    //double i = sqrt(-1);

    D = pow((cos(om * t1 / 2)), 2) + ((2 * i * sin(om * t1) / om * (Q2 + pow(om, 2) * Q1)) -
        (16 * D1 * ((pow(sin(om * t1 / 2), 2))));

    double phi = 1 / tan(pow((cos(om * t1 / 2)), 2) + ((2 * sin(om * t1) / om) * (Q2 + pow(om, 2) * Q1)) / (-16 * D1 * ((pow(sin(om * t1 / 2), 2)))));
    double a = abs(D);
    //printf("%f and %f\n",phi,a);  
    double ph1 = unwrap(phi); /*How to use unwrap function*/
}
for (m = 1; m <= N1; m++) {
    double t1 = (m - 1) * dt;
    N = ((i * cos(om * t1 / 2)) * ((pow(Gdot, 2) + pow((om * Gc), 2)) / om) - (4 * sin(om * t1 / 2)) * (Q2 * pow(Gc, 2) + Q1 * pow(Gdot, 2) - (Q1dot * Gdot * Gc))); /* How to use iota */
    double Ds = sqrt(a) * exp(i * ph1 / 2);
    double Ds1 = (a) * exp(i * ph1);
    //Ns(m) = (b) * exp(i * ps1);   
    double E = ((sin(om * t1 / 2)) / Ds1) * N;
    double S = (exp(-E)) / (Ds);
    double b = (pow(p0, 2) + pow((q0 * om), 2)) / (2 * om);
    double S1 = (exp(-i * om * t1 / 2)) * exp(b * (exp(-i * om * t1) - 1));
    fft(S);  /* How to calculate fft using gsl*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your code, the are some problems:

- it appears there is a missing parenthesis in the `D = pow((cos(om * ...` line.
- many variable declarations are missing (`m`, `D` ...)

You should post a complete compilable example for your problem and learn to space and indent your code to make it readable.

C99 and C11 have extended support for complex arithmetics.  You should define the complex variables as:

```
#include <complex.h>

complex double D;
```

The imaginary root of `-1` is defined as `I` (pronounced *ai*, not *iota*).

Identify which of the variables are complex and define them as such, use the complex versions for the math functions (add a `c` at the beginning of their name, such as `ccos()`, `csin()`...) avoid using `pow` to just square values, use `x * x` instead.

Comment: @Chaqrlie Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Can you guide me for unwrap function which is the root of my code?

Comment: Identify which of the variables are complex and define them as such, use the complex versions for the math functions, avoid using `pow` to just square values, use `x * x` instead.